# Powerapps automatic ID numbering

Tags: patch, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am doing an listing software, that asks for user input, and puts the data to a spreadsheet. I am having trouble with the id system. It works fine, when I add an item to the list. It increases the ID number with 1. But I need it to also automatically decrease the numbers, if I delete one of the items from the list. And I do not have any idea on how to do that. I use this code `Patch(Taulukko1;Defaults(Taulukko1);
{ID:CountRows(Taulukko1.ID)+1})´ to add an item to the list. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some more details. For example, if you have 500 records, and you remove record 450, should all records above 450 have their ID lowered by 1?
Its going to excel? You can add the row value of the item as the idea via Power Automate or in the spreadsheet itself, and PowerApps will pick that row up and automatically fill it.

Comment: Yes, all the records above the deleted one should have their ID lowered by 1

Comment: You have not provided more information. Based on what you stated earlier. Have Power Automate do it for you with a conditional function. For example: if ID > Removed ID, ID - 1